# Arrow keys not working in Excel 2013

Tags: keyboard, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a Dell laptop with Excel 2013 installed.  I am unable to use the arrow keys to move between cells.

I have seen similar questions where the Scroll Lock key was the solution, but not for me.  I do not have a Scroll Lock key, so I went to my OnScreen keyboard to click it, but it makes no difference.

Also, when I click a cell, I cannot type text in it, I have to double-click to be able to type...  is there also an option for that?

Any other ideas?

Comment: You haven't mentioned which version of Windows you are running. Have you got [Sticky Keys](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/make-keyboard-easier-to-use#1TC=windows-7) enabled?

Comment: It's Windows 7 Pro

Comment: Weird keyboard behaviour... it is always sticky keys of one form or another :)

Comment: In fact, they were *off*, but I turned them *on* and *off*, and all started to work normally again...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem, I went to my *Control Panel* -> *Ease of access* -> *Make the keyboard easier to use*

Then I checked the *Turn On Sticky Keys* option, and click OK.
Then go back and uncheck the *Turn On Sticky Keys* option, and click OK.

Problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

For those with HP laptops, the scroll lock function is mapped to  (function key + c).

This is the most infernal function in all of Excel. Please, Microsoft, fix this UX disaster and give the user a visible option to toggle this!